# Stuck at an algo which searches indexes of a list

Tags: python

The function searches the index of a value and if it is called again then it returns the next index of that  value. Here is what i tried, where I'm getting error is that my list is not getting overridden and after every call I am getting same result.
Note: I have not included linked list classes here
**If anyone knows a better way to make this function please suggest**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        self.previous = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

class DynamicSharpSearch(LinkedList):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.count = 0

        self.lim = 0    # using in search function

        for i in self.data:
            self.InsertatEnd(i)
            self.count += 1

        self.demlst = [-1 for i in range(self.count)]   # using in Search function only
        self.seclist = self.demlst


    def Search(self,n):
        x = self.head
        #demlst = [-1 for i in range(self.count)]
        y = 0
        tst = -1 # checks value if not in our data
        ##############################

        for i in range(self.count):

            if n == x.value:
                # demlst.append(i)
                self.demlst[y] = i
                tst = 0
            x = x.next
            y += 1
        ##############################
        if tst == -1:
            return -1
        else:
            pass
        """Demlist containes "indexes" """
        for i in range(self.count): 

            if self.seclist[i] >= 0:
                #y = self.seclist[i]

                self.seclist[i] = -1
                self.lim = i
                return i

obj = DynamicSharpSearch([53,4,52,7,5,4,5,5,5,6,4,2,4,5,459]) # c = 6
print(obj.Search(5))
print(obj.Search(5))
print(obj.Search(5))
```

**What output I am getting:**

```
4
4
4
```

Comment: made "seclist" outside the function Search so that after calling it next time my function use the old list

Comment: your return value depends only on 'seclist', which does not depend on demlst, the latter being the only thing that changes when you call obj.Search

Comment: oh, so should I use only demlst? for returning my value?

Comment: I'm just saying it would make sense you are getting the same result every time. Its not clear to me what 'LinkedList' here is , if that's defined elsewhere it may help to show it.

Comment: it's a class of linked list, im gonna show it in code

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to keep track of the last returned index for each value. 
 When the `Search` method is called, it looks to see if it's looked for that value before: `start_index = self.last_returned.get(n, 0)`.  If `start_index` is >0, then you fast-forward to that index before initiating the search. Once you've found what you're looking for, update the dictionary: `self.last_returned[n] = returned_index + 1`.  Why "+1"?  Because otherwise you'll get what you're getting right now, the same index returned over and over.  You need to start searching *after* the last index you returned.  (You'd want to make sure you're not storing a value which would result in an IndexError, however.)

Comment: Thanks dude, I will try your method